# iOS - Custom graphics for map view

Tags: ios, objective-c, dictionary, mkmapview

I am making a social networking app, and the user at one point is presented with a map with annotations. However, I would prefer to have custom graphics/tiles/topography for my map view. I would like a nice game-like theme to apply to my app, if you know what I mean.

Is this possible? Obviously not with the native API, but is there possibly a third party client I could use?

I have done prior research and have not found any solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have a first-hand experience with this one, but it seems to fit your requirements. [MapBox iOS SDK](http://mapbox.com/mobile/).

Comment: Thanks, that topography looks great! Dont even need to customize it!